# Why do I see SET in slave's slowlog?

Tags: redis

My setting is Redis master-slave replication. I am sure the slaves are read only because when I connect to slave and try to write data, "(error) READONLY You can't write against a read only slave." is returned.

However, when I check the slowlog there are SET commands, eg:
127.0.0.1:6379> slowlog get 1
1) 1) (integer) 1360
   2) (integer) 1544276677
   3) (integer) 10653
   4) 1) "SET"
      2) "some value"

Anyone can explain this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Redis replica is replaying commands sent from the master, so the `SET` command must have originated from it.

It is unclear why that command ended in the slowlog, but it could be because of any number of reasons (IO or CPU blockage). If this happened once I wouldn't worry about it, but if it is pathological you may want to review your replica's infrastructure and configuration.

Comment: "The Redis replica is replaying commands sent from the master", is it for replication from master to replica? Thank you.

Comment: Yes - the master is sending the replicas (a.k.a slaves) every write command it gets.